# Customize a jSpinner?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a complex calculator and the user has to select from a jSpinner a value between 1 and 12. Can you tell me how to set the jSpinner's minimum value to 1 and maximum value to 12?

Also how do you check which item is selected in a jSpinner?

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: You can find the answer to these and other questions at the tutorials: [JSpinner Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spinner with a minimum value of 1 and maximum value of 12.

```
SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(6, //initial value
                               1, //minimum value
                               12, //maximum value
                               1); // increment by
spinner.setModel(model);
```

And to get the value use:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getValue().toString());
```

Comment: Why are you converting an Integer value to a String and then parsing it with `Integer.parseInt`?  This seems very wasteful. Why not just cast it to Integer and call `intValue()` on it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, that approach is probably used because the getValue() return Object type. But in this case as SpinnerNumberModel is used it is to cast it to Number and then call intValue(). `((Number)spinner.getValue()).intValue()`. Or we can refer to the model instance and call `model.getNumber().intValue()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Vash. I wasn't aware of that method.